# sqlite3 unicode support in c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

```
std::ostringstream oss;
std::string s="תז";
oss << "insert into t values(" << s << ");"
this->sql = oss.str();    
rc = sqlite3_exec(c,this->sql.c_str(), callback, 0 , &zErrMsg);
```

`this->sql.c_str()` contains UTF-8 characters, after the execution of this line, if the data that inserted was unicode, this data in the database will be corrupted (one byte for each character instead of two bytes).
How to add Unicode support?

I want to write `תז` to the database, the bytes written to the database are: `fa e6` what needs to be written: `d7 aa d7 96`

Thanks.

Comment: How do you check if it's corrupted or not?

Comment: I checked the database file and I get one byte for each char instead of two bytes.

Comment: How did you 'check the database file'?

Comment: sqlite> select * from table;

Comment: Why do you think that `sql` is encoded in UTF-8? What exactly are you writing into `oss`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a variable-length encoding.
ASCII characters use one byte per character; others use two to four bytes.

SQLite never changes the bytes in a string.
The database contains the bytes `fa e6` because that are the contents of your original string `s`.

You must ensure that your source code file is encoded in UTF-8, or explicitly convert the string from its actual encoding into UTF-8.

Comment: Still I can't insert utf-8 to the db.

Comment: One byte per character **is** UTF-8.

Comment: Edit the question to show the string you're inserting, and what you're getting out.

Comment: @CL.: No, UTF-8 is potentially multiple bytes per character.

Comment: @KeithThompson That's why I wrote "ASCII".

Comment: I was replying to your comment.